# What is Distributed Marketing?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, servicecloud, distributed-marketing

Based on the [Distributed Marketing sales page](https://www.salesforce.com/products/marketing-cloud/distributed-marketing/#) and [help documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_dm_distributed_marketing.htm&type=5), **Distributed Marketing** allows for non-marketers to send emails in *Sales/Service/Community Cloud* using Marketing Cloud as the endpoint.

> "Enable nonmarketers to easily inform, market and sell to their
>   consumers at scale."

In the [demo video](https://www.salesforce.com/products/marketing-cloud/distributed-marketing/#), a Journey and corresponding data extension is created in Marketing Cloud and using an API event for the Entry Event. The data comes through the managed package from *Sales/Service/Community Cloud*. Non-marketers can inject Campaign Members into the journey.

The non-marketer (advisors, owners, partners, etc) can preview and personalize the journey emails and approve or disapprove contacts to send to in the campaign. It looks like the "personalization" piece is essentially a [Content Block](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_dm_install_content_block_overview.htm&type=5) within the email body. Non-marketers are only allowed to add the personalization to these content blocks.

Distributed Marketing requires a package to be installed: [Marketing Cloud Distributed Marketing package](https://sfdc.co/distributed_marketing).

All Distributed Marketing messages need to be linked to a journey. [The Quick Send](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_dm_set_up_quick_send.htm&type=5) option is basically just one email send tied to that journey with up to 50 journeys for Quick Sends.

I'm glad to see more robust integrations between Sales/Service/Community Cloud and Marketing Cloud.

*Has anyone had any experience with Distributed Sending and best practices around it?*

Likely the same best practices with Journey Builder apply here with some things to keep in mind with Quick Sends -- using just one email in the journey with journey settings set to "Re-entry at any time" or "Re-entry only after exiting"

The managed package seems to make it easy to connect a [campaign to a journey](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_dm_connect_campaign_to_journey.htm&type=5), but I'm wondering if there are any other "gotchas" to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

One of the gotcha's is a Send Cap limit that's been a huge issue for us. The send limit for Quick sends are 75, for Bulk Send via Quick Send Message is 100,000. But there hasn't been a clear way to limit a user from sending the full capacity.

Resource:  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_dm_send_a_bulk_message_from_quick_send_message_records.htm&type=5

The second issue has been around the Monthly Sending limits for Quick Sends. Our team has established a send cap for the month to be 1000. However, our Sales team weren't seeing their allotment refresh each month. Support confirmed the send cap works on a rolling basis of either 1, 7, or 30 days, so the cap will continually be recalibrating based on the send activity (creation date) set in the DM Admin settings.

Resource:  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_dm_administer_frequency_capping.htm&type=5